# Double click event using Robot class in awt package

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

I have already seen lot of threads regarding double click events using `MouseEvent`. But that is not what I am looking for. I recently started using `Robot` class and came across few functions of mouse like `mouseMove(x,y)`, `mouseRelease(int buttons)`.

`Robot` class provides `mousePress(int button);` function as well. I have tried this.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(305, 450);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
```

But this is a single click event. What I am trying to achieve is the double click event using `Robot` class. Is it possible to achieve that ? If so. then how ?

Comment: Repeat the last two lines right again

Comment: @XtremeBaumer :) Yes thank you, so simple !! and so silly me

Comment: @XtremeBaumer wanna share your comment as an answer ?

Comment: Its already an answer. Accept that one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Robot` class doesn't provide a way of double-clicking. You'll have to implement that yourself. Think about what a double-click really is, it's two clicks in quick succession. (Depending on your OS settings, the required time between clicks might vary.)

So you really just need to click twice really quickly:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(305, 450);
// first click
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
// second click
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
```

You might also want to add a few milliseconds of delay between the two clicks, as some things might not respond well to too-fast clicks.